# How do I run a task-specific block at configuration time in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm writing a couple Gradle tasks, and when `publishA` runs I want to publish to one Artifactory repository, and when `publishB` runs I want to publish to a different one. I have the following code:

```
task publishA() {
  println "In project"
  project.ext.artifactory_target = 'foo'
}

task publishB() {
  println "In candidate"
  project.ext.artifactory_target = 'bar'
}

artifactory {
  contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
  publish {
    repository {
      repoKey = "${artifactory_target}"
      maven = true
      username = "${artifactory_user}"
      password = "${artifactory_password}"
    }
  }
}
```

... but obviously, this doesn't work, because the configuration blocks for both `publishA` and `publishB` run. How do I define code that should run at configuration time, but only if the task which contains it is defined?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Especially: 'but only if the task which contains it is defined'. Could You explain a bit?

Comment: Conditional configuration based on which tasks are going to be executed is problematic, and should generally be avoided. I'm fairly sure that the Artifactory plugin provides a better way to publish to different repositories, although I haven't checked. Gradle's own publishing facilities certainly do.

Comment: @Opal: Currently, both "In project" and "In candidate" print. I only want to run one or the other, depending on which task I ran.

Comment: The code that defines the task's behavior needs to go into a *task action*. The ad-hoc way to add a task action is `myTask.doLast { ... }`. However, a task action shouldn't generally configure stuff, since configuration should happen in the configuration phase (and task actions run in the execution phase).

Comment: I need to set variables which are available to the artifactory task, at configuration time.

Comment: `artifactory` is a model object, and `artifactoryPublish` is the task. Perhaps you can declare a second such task, and configure it with a different repository (best check the docs or ask the authors of the plugin). Otherwise, consider using Gradle's built-in publishing support. If you are still aiming for conditional configuration, you could do so based on `gradle.startParameter.taskNames` or `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady` (both have their caveats). The Gradle User Guide has more on the latter callback. A safer way is to do conditional configuration based on a system or project property.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```groovy
project.ext.artifactory_target = 'your_target_foo'

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { TaskExecutionGraph taskGraph ->
    if(taskGraph.hasTask(your_candiate_target_name)) {
        project.ext.artifactory_target = "your_target_bar"
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = {project.artifactory_target} // <- Location of braces is important.
            maven = true
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
```

There are three things happening in the code above. First, a custom variable is defined to hold your target. Second, a hook is created which will be executed after Gradle has finished figuring out all of the tasks it is going to execute. Within this hook, the custom variable we already defined is updated if we are going to execute your specific task. Finally, in the artifactory configuration, we pass a closure that returns the current value of the variable that we've been playing around with above.

Gradle has three distinct phases to a build, the Initialization Phase, the Configuration Phase, and the Execution Phase. The Initialization phase is when Gradle sets itself up, the Configuration phase is when it figures out what it needs to do and what tasks to run, and then the Execution Phase is when it actually does everything. Most of the stuff in a .gradle file happens in the Configuration phase. You can sort of think of most blocks in a .gradle file as structures that set up data to be passed to tasks, which are then run in the Execution Phase. By moving the evaluation of our variable to a closure, we are moving this portion of the logic from the Configuration phase to the Execution Phase, allowing us to do some interesting stuff like customizing it's contents based on which tasks are being executed.

For more information on Gradle's life cycle, [take a look here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).